# Clipboard in Safari and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, safari, clipboard

I found a few articles how clipboard works in IE and Firefox **without flash**, but I did not find any example regarding to Safari and Chrome. Could somebody share with me example or provide link?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to manually set the system clipboard contents from JavaScript running in Safari or Chrome? Unfortunately, this capability was disabled a long while ago due to security reasons (previously, it had been possible to do that using execCommand(), but no more.) Sorry I cannot provide you a link to the respective WebKit bugzilla issue offhand. I'd be curious, though, if someone had a working solution.